# How can I use bash-only syntax in CMD in a Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am creating a `Dockerfile` which starts a Java application. This Java application is given a file path which contains the output of `ls -l`.

(Note that in my real `Dockerfile` I am not doing `ls - l` but rather complex commands. I altered that to `ls - l` to simplify the question.)

I tried the following:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ARG JAR
COPY target/$JAR /app/app.jar

CMD java -jar /app/app.jar <( ls -l )
```

This `bash` `<( ... )` construction should create a temporary file containing the output of `ls -l`.

When starting the Docker file, I get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Now, `sh` does not support the `<( ... )` construction, hence the error. How can I start the application safely via `bash` instead of `sh`? With safely I mean that the Java app still will receive all OS signals (`SIGHUP`, ...) and react appropriately.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Sounds like the command is complex enough to write a separate script, and execute *that* as the command line. Don't try to fit too much into the Dockerfile itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your command with a JSON list, for which the first two elements are `bash` `-c`, and the last element is the shell command you actually want to run.

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "exec java -jar /app/app.jar <( ls -l )"]
```

To generate such an array for a more complex command, you might consider using `jq` to ensure that syntax is correct, even for input with backslashes, newlines or quotes:

```
jq -cnRs '["bash", "-c", input]' <<'EOF'
# you can put other shell commands here if you need to
exec java -jar /app/app.jar <( ls -l )
EOF
```

`exec` ensures that the `java` instance replaces `bash`, and thus is sent signals directly.

Comment: This is great, the application is now starting and getting all signals. Thank you. I am getting `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/dev/fd/63` in the application though, I'll have to inspect that further.

Comment: I wonder if maybe the application you're running expects the file handle given to be seekable (so it can be read more than once)? If so, it won't work with `<(...)` and you might need to fall back to a temporary file (or switch to zsh, with its `=(...)` construct).

Comment: That's a good question. When I do that directly on my host (that is, not via Docker), it works as expected. It's an input file which should be read just once. So I guess it should work.

Comment: Interesting. If you're using the same JVM, it should be reproducible on the host if it were closing inherited file descriptors; and bash 4.4.23 doesn't have any problems combining process substitution and `exec`. Might check whether `/dev/fd` is set up properly (as a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`) in the Docker environment, just as a caution. I'll be curious to hear what the issue was if you run that one down.

Comment: Sorry, that error was completely unrelated. I was getting a `FileNotFoundException`, due to an incorrect `COPY` `Dockerfile` instruction. (It kinda sucks that a no-copy doesn't give an error.) After fixing this, it works flawlessly. Thanks again for passing all this knowledge here!

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing complex things on startup it's often easier to write them into a script than try to build a very complicated command line.  Once you're doing that, you can use the set of primitives that are available in [the POSIX shell standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18), even if they require multiple commands to do things that GNU bash could do inline.

For this I might write a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ls -l >/ls-l.txt
exec java -jar /app/app.jar /ls-l.txt
```

and then copy it in as the default thing your image runs

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jre
ARG JAR
COPY target/$JAR /app/app.jar
COPY launch-app.sh /usr/bin/app
# RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/app, if it's not already executable
CMD ["app"]
```